# Angular Validation not working with reference variables

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

Below is my component.html

```
    <form (ngSubmit)="save(myForm.form)" #myForm="ngForm" novalidate>
              <select required id="language" [(ngModel)]="myModel.language" name="language" #language="ngModel">
                  <option *ngFor="let lang of languages" value={{lang.key}}>
                    {{lang.value}}
                  </option>
              </select>
              <div *ngIf="myForm.submitted && language.invalid" class="ErrorTxt">
                  <div *ngIf="language.errors.required">Language is required</div>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default ">Save</button>
    </form>
```

It should show message "Language is required" when user click on submit without selecting a value from dropdown , but it does not.

I tried printing value of reference variables like below

```
{{myForm.submitted}}-{{language.invalid}}-{{language.errors.required}}
```

and got this output all the time:

> false-true-true

After clicking on submit button, `{{myForm.submitted}}` should be `true` but it is always set to `false`. The save method is defined as follows in my component.ts file:

```js
           save(form: any) {
            if (!form.valid) {
              let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("ng-invalid");
              if (elements.length > 1) {
                (elements[1] as HTMLElement).focus();
              }
              return;
            }
            // save code here 
           }
```

Can someone please suggest whats wrong with this validation and how to make it work ?

Comment: add a option with value null `<option [ngValue]="null" hidden [disabled]="true" >Select language</option>`" (and give at first the value null. required is fullfilled only else if the value is null

Comment: not working , submitted still show false , for your information this is also happening for input type text and file